# How to Query Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good nigth,I have a problem that I do not know how to solve it. I have three models in my application:

```
class Hecho(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    hecho = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Beneficiario(models.Model):
    tipoDocumento = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    numeroDocumento = models.IntegerField()
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class HechoBeneficiario(models.Model):
    beneficiario = models.ForeignKey(Beneficiario)
    hecho = models.ForeignKey(HechoVictimizante)
```

As you can see the model HechoBeneficiario relates the other two models.
My problem is like using the Beneficiario model can I get the model Hecho and paint this in a template?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What query are you even trying to make? Have you read the documentation on "making queries"?

Comment: What you want to do? any desired Output?Please Edit your question and ask it properly

Comment: First Google result for 'How to query django': https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 0):

In your situation better to use [many to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) field. Your models will look like this:

```
class Beneficiario(models.Model):
        tipoDocumento = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        numeroDocumento = models.IntegerField()
        nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Hecho(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    hecho = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    beneficiarios = models.ManyToManyField(Beneficiario, related_name='hechos')
```

And you can get all hechos for Beneficiario using this code:

```
hechos = beneficiario_object.hechos.all()
```

And get all Beneficiario for hecho using this code:

```
beneficiarios = hecho_object.beneficiarios.all()
```

But you should know that django will hit database every time when you try to access many to many field. For prevent this you can use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) when retrieving all your Beneficiario models, like this:

```
beneficiarios = Beneficiario.objects.prefetch_related('hechos')
for beneficiario in beneficiarios:
    print(beneficiario.hechos.all())
```

It will hit database only 2 times.